# Show the arrowLeft back button with a disabled header

Tags: react-native

hello community im relatively new to React native I want to show the arrow left to go back to screens !! when i run my code it doesnt show up , and i think i have to disable my `headershown:flase` and i put it on commentary ! but unfortunately i have this error **Objects are not valid as a React child (found:Object with keys{left})**  This is my code :
**App.js**

```
  <Stack.Navigator
   initialRouteName="Home"
   >
     <Stack.Screen
  name="Home"
   component={HomeScreen}
   options={{
     headerShown:false
   }}
   />
   <Stack.Screen
  name="Sign In"
   component={SignIn}
   options={{
    headerShown:false,
     header: ({ goBack }) => ({
      left: ( <Icon name={'arrowleft'} onPress={ () => { goBack() } }  /> ),  
      })
   }}
   />
  <Stack.Screen
  name="Registration"
   component={Registration}
   options={{
     headerShown:false,
     header: ({ goBack }) => ({
      left: ( <Icon name={'arrowleft'} onPress={ () => { goBack() } }  /> ),  
      })
   }}
   />
   </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your options like so:

```js
options={{
  headerTransparent: true,
  headerBackImage: () => <Icon name={'arrowLeft'} />,
}}
```

This will change only the back icon (you might add some styling to position it as you want), and ReactNavigation will handle press events.

I don't think you want to use `headerShown: false` as this will hide the entire navigation bar, back button included.

The error you are receiving is due to the fact that the API changed a few versions back and the `header` property now requires a component to render, not an object.

Comment: I have to benefit from that space above and try to add an arrow to back to screen .THats why i have to remain ````headerShown : false ````

Comment: `headerSbown: false` will remove all of it, while you just want it to be transparent. Try `headerTransparent: true` instead. It really is all in the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#headertransparent